# Fallback for products which not exists in other storeview

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language, 404, stores

We are running a Magento 1.9 multi store environment. Due to German regulations, we cannot offer a range of products in Germany, which brings us to an issue that we need to disable those products in the catalog of the German store view.

Now we have an issue that when a user switches from /en/product_a/ to /de/product_a/ the user gets a **404**. Is there any solution to catch the identity of product_a and tell the user this product is not available in this store view but is available in other store views?

Comment: you can used magento registry and do custom code to show this message.

Comment: The Magento registry will recognize products urls from other storeviews?

Comment: registry give you current product details. Here you can used that detail.